# Aptly does not create a mirror with expected kernel version

Tags: aptly

I am trying to create a mirror using aptly. I would like this mirror to contain a specific version of the kernel and the kernel headers. Specifically I would like it to contain linux-image-6.2.0-35-generic and linux-headers-6.2.0-35-generic.

So I do the following:

```
export PACKAGE_FILTER="Name (= linux-image-generic)  | Name (= linux-headers-generic)"
```

and

```
aptly -filter-with-deps -with-udebs -dep-follow-recommends -dep-follow-all-variants -filter="$PACKAGE_FILTER" -architectures=amd64 mirror create jammy-1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy
aptly -filter-with-deps -with-udebs -dep-follow-recommends -dep-follow-all-variants -filter="$PACKAGE_FILTER" -architectures=amd64 mirror create jammy-updates http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates
aptly -filter-with-deps -with-udebs -dep-follow-recommends -dep-follow-all-variants -filter="$PACKAGE_FILTER" -architectures=amd64 mirror create jammy-security http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security
```

I do an aptly mirror update for all the newly created mirrors.

So If I do

```
aptly mirror show -with-packages=true jammy-1
aptly mirror show -with-packages=true jammy-updates
aptly mirror show -with-packages=true jammy-security
```

I would expect the that the 6.2.0-35 version would show up somewhere in the list. However, this is not the case, I get:

5.15.0-25 (for jammy-1) 5.15.0-87 (for jammy-updates, and security)

If I do:

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

I get plenty of different versions, so I must be missing something. The question is what?